# for making boostrap cdn work, do I need also the javascript cdn or only css, or all 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

which one do I need to use?
https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

CSS or JS or BUNDLE or all 3?
[image]

> I want to use buttons styling, grid, card (and maybe dropdown but in the future)
>
> ```html
> <!-- which one? -->
>
> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
>
> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
>
> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
> ```

Comment: You would just need the first and the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:**
if you want basic styling, use a CSS-only file.

if you need interactivity then use also javascript

- `CSS` is **mandatory**
- `JS` is **optional**

---

I suggest seeing the official docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/

> *"Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages, right before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins."*

they basically say if you want some extra functionality then go for javascript one (for example you want a tooltip, a dropdown that opens and close)

if you want instead of coloring, or changing size, then use only the CSS link. (buttons are one of this case)

---

however, if you use this only to learn, I suggest importing all the files there, for not have any import issues.

 once you will learn it, then try to use one cdn link at the time.

---

if you want to use bootstrap in the production site, then maybe try using the `npm` package instead.

```
npm i bootstrap
```

(but first try to learn using CDN, the once you know the basics, then use npm)

---

> also remember to use `<link>` tag to make HTML import the CSS file, by copy the first link appear you once you open the dropdown
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use dropdowns, poppers and tooltips, use all. If you only need styles use bootstrap.min.css only.